# mongodb and a "deep" mongoexport

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

Is it possible to do a "deep" export using mongoexport hence resolving any possible DBRef to some other object within the mongo database?

Example:

lets say one of my collections "application" contains a document with a property:

```
{
    "service" : DBRef("service", NumberLong(1))
}
```

Is it possible for mongoexport to do some deep export resolving this dbref to the actual object with its underlying information instead of outing it like follows in the json file:

```
"service" : { "$ref" : "service", "$id" : 1 }
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

[Database References (aka DBRefs)](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/) are only a notational data convention in MongoDB and do not (as at MongoDB 2.4) have any special server-side support for populating the references.

Many application drivers or frameworks have [support for working with DBRefs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/#support), but do so by generating additional queries to get the referenced documents.

If you want to populate DBRefs when exporting data, you will have to write your own export script.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately currently mongodb does not implement it, it will export data as csv, or json, actually it will use an Extended JSON implementation: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/

It represents DBRef as data_ref: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#data_ref

Regards,
Moacy